# Reinstall vim with python3 support

Tags: python-3.x, vim, vim-plugin

I installed Vim 7.4 a few months ago (sudo apt-get install vim) on Ubuntu 16.04 and now I'm trying to install plugins that require python3 support.

How can I reinstall/uppgrade vim to support python3?

Comment: Back when I was still using Ubuntu, [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) was the most reliable way to get a beefy Vim. Be sure to install `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk`, not just `vim`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install vim-nox
```

Fixed it for me. Didn't even have to uninstall my current vim or anything else. Thanks to Romainl for your comment!